# AES 128 have different results in Arduino ESP8266 and Online Tool

Tags: encryption, arduino, aes

I want to encrypt text by AES 128 CBC, but the results is different in Arduino and online tool. I tried different Arduino library, but still have same problem. 
my code in arduino as follow.

```
#include <Crypto.h>
#include <ebase64.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

byte key[BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};
byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE] = {0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};

void bufferSize(char* text, int &length)
{
int i = strlen(text);
int buf = round(i / BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE;
length = (buf < i) ? buf + BLOCK_SIZE : length = buf;
}

void encrypt(char* plain_text, char* output, int length)
{
byte enciphered[length];

AES aesEncryptor(key, iv, AES::AES_MODE_128, AES::CIPHER_ENCRYPT);
aesEncryptor.process((uint8_t*)plain_text, enciphered, length);

int encrypted_size = sizeof(enciphered);
char encoded[encrypted_size];
base64_encode(encoded, (char*)enciphered, encrypted_size);

strcpy(output, encoded);
}

void decrypt(char* enciphered, char* output, int length)
{
length = length + 1; //re-adjust
int decodedLen = base64_dec_len(enciphered, length);
char decoded[length];

Serial.println(enciphered);
base64_decode(decoded, enciphered, length);
bufferSize(enciphered, length);
byte deciphered[length];
AES aesDecryptor(key, iv, AES::AES_MODE_128, AES::CIPHER_DECRYPT);

aesDecryptor.process((uint8_t*)decoded, deciphered, length);
strcpy(output, (char*)deciphered);
}

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
while (!Serial) {
; //wait
}

char plain_text[] = "Now is the time ABCDABC";

// encrypt
int length = 0;
bufferSize(plain_text, length);
Serial.println(length);
char encrypted[length];
encrypt(plain_text, encrypted, length);

Serial.println(encrypted);

// decrypt

length = strlen(encrypted);
char decrypted[length];
decrypt(encrypted, decrypted, length);

Serial.println(decrypted);
}
void loop()
{
}
```

Key and IV:

{0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};

or

{ '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };

Text: "Now is the time ABCDABC";

the encrypted is

**1a7OeiH628V7IIoLU6+3n70Dzp6FBQjlGPxSwnuXdzo=**

and the AES online tool.
[https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption]

Key : 0000000000000000

IV  : 0000000000000000

Text: Now is the time ABCDABC

I'm encrypt in web and the result is

**1a7OeiH628V7IIoLU6+3n7ILev6IwcZYVNLalS/TBEg=**

So I can't decrypt each other. Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The input may not be hex as you thought

Comment: Hi kelalaka, I change the key and iv to 0x00 in arduino, it have more different result.

Comment: See the answer for TXAggie00 comment on your the online tool's website. It is better to ask there!

Comment: @Neo Try it with 16 characters long input text and write result.

Comment: @Matej Thank you your reply, I tried input text as "1234567890123456" or {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6'} ,the result still different. 
gRqCOq4Dqu/Z4AZ6oJXTsLVhN8H/qIN+qWRcSvognG8=
from online tool, and gRqCOq4Dqu/Z4AZ6oJXTsAMGPHKNJNqHmqFj9aC1ecM= 
from arduino.
the result from online tool is correct. because it can decrypt by other online tool. I think the AES in arduino need to adjust, but I don't know how to adjust.

Comment: Can you test with an input string longer than 32 characters?

Comment: I think problem is in different padding than online platform has.

Comment: @Guille Thank you your suggestion. the results same with 16 characters, and the encrypt results still same in the first part and different in the end part.

Comment: AES is a block cypher. If only the last part differs, the implementation is correct but the last block has a different result. It probably is because of the different padding bytes used, as @Matej suggested. Check if you can set the padding to match the one from the online tool.

Comment: @Guille Thanks your suggestion. I tried nopadding function, and I got the same result. I think it need a person who understand AES very detail can adjust this. So I use 3DES for arduino now. Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is one of these instances where the author of [a crypto library](https://github.com/intrbiz/arduino-crypto/blob/master/Crypto.h) is even more clueless than authors of "online tools" that perform such feat:

```
   /**
     * Either encrypt or decrypt [in] and store into [out] for [length] bytes, applying padding as needed
     * 
     * Note: the length must be a multiple of 16 bytes
     */
    void process(const uint8_t *in, uint8_t *out, int length);
```

Now it isn't specified which padding is used, nor how it is removed. Furthermore, obviously the input should not always be a multiple of 16, that doesn't make any sense.

However, decryption without padding can be used to recover the plaintext:

```
4e6f77206973207468652074696d6520414243444142430020000000feefeffe
4e6f77206973207468652074696d652041424344414243090909090909090909
 N o w   i s   t h e   t i m e   A B C D A B C
```

Here the first one is your encryption. Obviously it doesn't show a correct padding at all. It's a zero byte, a `02` byte and then some zero's followed by `feefeffe` which terribly looks like a method to detect uninitialized memory or something like it. The online library uses PKCS#7 compatible padding.

The first idea for me when looking at the code is that you were wrong when declaring the array containing the ciphertext:

```
byte enciphered[length];
```

obviously that's not correct if the ciphertext size expands the plaintext size due to padding. So you have a possible buffer overrun there. However, as you still get back the original plaintext even for the last block, the library must be in error as well.

Moral of the story: don't use horrible one-person libraries on GitHub. Libraries need to be tested and have a team behind it to be trustworthy enough for crypto.

Comment: Thank you your answer. Actually I tried many different library before, and this library's example result is the most similar with online tool. I still can not fix the different, so I use 3DES for arduino now. Because it can decrypt by online tool.

If someone has same situation with me, maybe you can try this.
https://github.com/Octoate/ArduinoDES

Comment: Don't use 3DES, just pad the plaintext yourself. PKCS#7 padding is easy to implement, just add one byte valued `01` if you need one byte, all the way up to 16 bytes valued `16` if that is required (PKCS#7 padding is *always* performed). Then you'd be compatible with all the other libraries out there (if they are reasonably up to date anyway). Unpadding: read the last byte, check if it is 16 (`10` hex) or smaller, then strip away the other bytes. **Beware of padding oracle attacks**. Verify a HMAC over the ciphertext before unpadding if oracle attacks are a possibility.

Comment: Thanks you. but this library has PKSC#7 function, and it doesn't change anything. I think the problem is IV rules... I observed some of tool can be decrypt from arduino encrypt, but arduino can not decrypt from other tool encrypt.

Comment: The IV has nothing to do with it as the first part of the ciphertext decrypts correctly, and that's what the IV should definitely change. I think the padding / unpadding is simply not implemented correctly, so you have to either adjust the library or program it yourself. The documentation of the function is also incorrect. When I see such things I generally assume that the library itself is programmed with the same lack of vigilance (and in my experience, it usually is).

Comment: Glad to you share the information to me. But I decrypt data from other online tool.  It still can't work, the result has the original text and garbled text, I think this part doesn't matter with padding. I also tried 16/32 long characters input text, it has same result as before. I think some of parameter in library is different with other online tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your encrypted data in both cases is correct.

```
1a7OeiH628V7IIoLU6+3n70Dzp6FBQjlGPxSwnuXdzo=
```

Decodes as:

```
d5 ae ce 7a 21 fa db c5 7b 20 8a 0b 53 af b7 9f 

bd 03 ce 9e 85 05 08 e5 18 fc 52 c2 7b 97 77 3a
```

And

```
1a7OeiH628V7IIoLU6+3n7ILev6IwcZYVNLalS/TBEg=
```

Decodes as:

```
d5 ae ce 7a 21 fa db c5 7b 20 8a 0b 53 af b7 9f 

b2 0b 7a fe 88 c1 c6 58 54 d2 da 95 2f d3 04 48
```

As you can see the first 16 bytes are OK. That can be interpreted as: the Key and IV are the same in both cases.
And as in your case if complete blocks are OK, and only the last block have issues, seems that the problem is in the padding mode.

Your Text: "Now is the time ABCDABC" has 24 bytes (with the null end char), but this encryption algorithm needs multiples of 16 bytes. Therefore, it must be padded up to 32 bytes. It will have 8 padding bytes. But with what value?

I was experimenting same issues with Arduino AESLib.
And I found that versions below 2.0 supports only one padding mode (unfortunately incompatible with online tools), the only option, do it myself.
But in version 2.0.2 they improved it and add support for multiple modes.

Most online tools use as default PKCS7 padding, but Arduino AESLib initialize with Array mode for compatibility reasons.

So I needed to call:

```
aes.setPadMode(paddingMode::CMS);
```

before using `do_aes_encrypt`, `do_aes_decrypt` functions.

These functions manage all padding, sizing issues according to the configuration.

In your case you case the call to

```
aesEncryptor.process((uint8_t*)plain_text, enciphered, length);
```

It doesn't have padding management and it must be done prior to the call.

So what is happening is that the function is using an additional 8 bytes after the end of plain_text[] array as padding with its uninitialized memory value.